# Why doesn't Docker Compose respect my PostgreSQL login information?

Tags: postgresql, docker

When using this `docker-compose.yml` file, why can't I login to the `postgres-testing` database using
`postgresql://jens2:meindertsma2@localhost:5432/postgres-testing?schema=public`
as a URL? I have to use
`postgresql://jens1:meindertsma1@localhost:5432/postgres-testing?schema=public` instead. Why is this? How can I make Docker Compose respect my different environment variables for each image?

```
services:
  postgres-development:
    image: "postgres:14"
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=jens1
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=meindertsma1
        - POSTGRES_DB=postgres-development
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
 postgres-testing:
   image: "postgres:14"
   environment:
     - POSTGRES_USER=jens2
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=meindertsma2
     - POSTGRES_DB=postgres-testing
   ports:
     - "5433:5432"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working as intended.

You are exposing your first service (user `jens1`) with a local host port `5432`
You are exposing your second service (user `jens2`) with a local host port `5433`

Thus when you connect to the port `5432`, you are connecting to the first container. Why would you expect to be able to connect to the first container with user `jens2`?